# Search Firestore query don't show data in RecycleView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

**this is my data in Firestore**
[I want to show this name "mouad"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoIfJ.png)

**This is my code**

```
ublic class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mMainList;
    private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    private List usersList;
    private CustomAdapter adapterRe;
    EditText editText;
    Button btnSearch;
    String  name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_firebase);

        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        usersList = new ArrayList();
        adapterRe = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), usersList);

        mMainList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyvle);
      //  mMainList.setHasFixedSize(true);
     //   mMainList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
     //   mMainList.setAdapter(adapterRe);


        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SearchUserFirebase();
            }
        });



    }

    private void SearchUserFirebase() {
        name = editText.getText().toString();
        if(!name.isEmpty()){

            Query query =  mFirestore.collection("Movies").orderBy("name" ).startAt(name).endAt(name + "\uf8ff");
            query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                   if (e != null){

                       Log.d("TAG", "Error : " + e.getMessage());
                   }
                   ArrayList adsList = new ArrayList();

                   for(DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

                       if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                           Movies users = doc.getDocument().toObject(Movies.class);
                           usersList.add(users);
                           adapterRe.notifyDataSetChanged();

                       }
                   }

                   Log.d("TAG", "no of records of the search is " + adsList.size());

               }
           });

        }
    }
    }
```

**This is error**

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8psMd.png)

Comment: Please add the code in text format and not in a picture.

Comment: Post the whole activity code @mouad zizi

Comment: Remove this lines from comment -
     //   mMainList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
     //   mMainList.setAdapter(adapterRe); and your error will be resolved.

Comment: Did that worked for you @mouadzizi ?

Comment: no it doesn't  worck

Comment: i fix it when i add this line in the loop 
  mMainList.setAdapter(adapterRe);

Comment: i have a new error 
+ When I search for a word, I only get the addresses that start with the same word you entered
Is there any way to bring me even the middle words inside the titles, for example
This is the title of "Game of Throns"
If only "throns" are introduced to any movie

Comment: When I search for a word, the first letter begins with a smaller letter showing the result
When the same word is pronounced but the first letter is large the result does not appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this error appears when you are trying to set the adapter from a background thread and **not** from the "main" thread (for example inside the `onCreate()` method).

If you are trying to set the adapter from a "delayed" method like inside the `onEvent()` method, this warning will always appear.

To solve this, move the creation of the adapter in the same thread and get the following line of code out of that for loop.

```
adapterRe.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: nothing !? the error stile 
TAG: no of records of the search is 0

Comment: i fix it when i add this line in the loop 
  mMainList.setAdapter(adapterRe);

Comment: When I search for a word, the first letter begins with a smaller letter showing the result
When the same word is pronounced but the first letter is large the result does not appear

Comment: i have a new error 
+ When I search for a word, I only get the addresses that start with the same word you entered
Is there any way to bring me even the middle words inside the titles, for example
This is the title of "Game of Throns"
If only "throns" are introduced to any movie

Comment: Yes, you can take a look at my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452823/it-is-possible-to-have-a-contains-search-query-in-firebase/51456002)**.

Comment: not that i use Query it's work for me but didn't get all data had  like names

Answer (score 3):

Do you have an empty constructor inside the "Movies.java" file?

```
 public Movies() {
      //Necessary to retrieve data
 }
```