# It is possible to have a contains search query in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried this:

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = 
myRef.orderByChild("from").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText+"\uf8ff");
```

but i want something like this

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = 
myRef.orderByChild("from").contains(searchText);
```

it is possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For small datasets you can use the following code:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String from = ds.child("from").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(from);
        }

        for(String str : list) {
            if(str.contains(searchText)) {
                Log.d("TAG", "String found!");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
};
myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

This solution is not recommended for large datasets because you'll need to download the entire node in order to make a search. In this case, [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) are recommended.

If you intend to use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), I recommend you to see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)**. For more information, I also recommend you see this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6x-ZJp-10)**.

Comment: Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: can you please elaborate what do you mean by "small datasets"? how many children in a single node can be considered as small datasets?

Comment: @QadirHussain As many as I you'll have a decent cost, otherwise you should implement one of those third party services.

Answer (score 2):

You need maybe this:

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = myRef.orderByChild("from").equalTo(searchText + "\uf8ff");
```

**EDIT**

I guess it is not possible using firebase, it needs a special service in order to be done. A service that has to do with advanced searching (something like elastic search).

Comment: sorry but it did not work

Comment: @AngeloLucena check the edit.

Comment: ok thanks maybe I will try elastic search

Comment: @dynamiclynk: That's a weird comment to make given that this answer doesn't include a link. Did you choose the wrong option during review?