# checking substring from firebase and retriving data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ48Z.jpg)

I want to check weather string i have is substring of Treats field and if yes then how to retrive data of remaining fields and display it. i want to do this for all doctors.

Comment: The Firebase Database doesn't support queries that search for a substring. If this functionality is required for your app, consider using another/additional service. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452823/it-is-possible-to-have-a-contains-search-query-in-firebase and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string

Comment: how  to integrate elasticsearch in dialogflow?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to loop through each doctor and check if your string is a substring. Save each doctor that has your substring and display the rest of their data.

Answer (score 0):

After setting up firebase for your project and adding all of the SDKs (if you haven't done that yet, do that [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?authuser=0)), you can retrieve data by using this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
var postId = i
var findTreat = firebase.database().ref('Doctor/' + postId + '/Treats');
  findTreat.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  updatefindTreat(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
}
```

I found this using the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0). Let me know if this works!