# How to filter a ListView taken from Firebase using TextField and display the matched items on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, filter

I want to make a search on a TextField that displays the results of a search made on CloudFirestore. This code provides the results when I print. How can I display it on the interface? Besides I should say that, when I try the method arrayContains, in order to get the results based on parts of a string, my print doesn't work, just with the whole string (isEqualTo).

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Home.dart';


void main ()async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),

  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextEditingController _controllerField = TextEditingController();

  final CollectionReference _materias =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('materias');
List searchResult = [];

   searchFF(String query) async{
    final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('materias')
        .where('unidades_tematicas',
     isEqualTo: query).get();

setState(() {
  searchResult = result.docs.map((x) => x.data()).toList();
  print(searchResult);
});
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("BNCC - Matemática"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body:
        Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _controllerField,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: "Buscar"
                ),
                onChanged: (query) {
                  searchFF(query);
                },
              ),


              StreamBuilder(
                stream: _materias.snapshots(),
                builder: (context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
                  if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {

                       return
                          Expanded(child:
                          ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,

                        itemBuilder: (context, indice) {
                          DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                          streamSnapshot.data!.docs[indice];
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                    documentSnapshot['unidades_tematicas']),
                                subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot['habilidades']),
                              )
                              ],

                          );
                        }));
                  }
                  return Container(
                  );
                },
              )
            ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

The interface looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post. For the second part, it sounds like you're trying to use `array-contains` to implement partial string match, which isn't what it does. For more on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73612653/209103 and many more from https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+query+string+contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the search results in your UI, you'll want to change your code around to always use streams.

So first off: add a field with the stream of `_materias` to your widget's state, rather than just the reference:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextEditingController _controllerField = TextEditingController();

  final CollectionReference _materias =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('materias');
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream = _materias.snapshots()

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
              StreamBuilder(
                stream: _stream,
  ...
```

Now when you implement the search, you can just replace the `_stream` value with a stream of the filtered results. That's look something like this:

```
searchFF(String query) async {
  const query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('materias')
        .where('unidades_tematicas', isEqualTo: query);
  
  setState(() {
    _stream = query.snapshots();
  });
}
```

This is quite similar to the example in the Firebase documentation on [showing realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart), so I recommend keeping that handy while making the changes to your code.